# What's the preferred method of creating different page templates

Tags: 7, theming

Basically, I want to give my articles and blog entries a different class on the body so I can style them independently.

I am given to understand that the best way to do this is with creating custom tpl files

I'm working in a custom built theme that is pretty much running just on a page.tpl.php and a stylesheet.

How would I do this easily in Drupal 7? I tried [this method for drupal 6](http://www.shekhargovindarajan.com/tips-n-tricks/drupal-6-different-page-templates-for-different-content-types/) but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should by there by default.

For example, the body classes on my test site look like this for a simplenews node:

```
<body class="html not-front logged-in one-sidebar sidebar-first page-node page-node- page-node-90 node-type-simplenews toolbar toolbar-drawer i18n-en" >
```

As you can see, there is node-type-simplenews, among many other things.

Those classes are defined in [template_preprocess_html()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7) and are using in html.tpl.php (not page.tpl.php, unless you've overriden that. If so, you need to duplicate the logic in that function for your page.tpl.php.

Comment: Wow you're right. I thought I had checked that, but I had not realized that chrome developer tools summarizes the inheritence list at the bottom.. i thought it was showing me everything.